# Find from elisp if Emacs buffer is modified

Tags: emacs, elisp, modeline

I'm customizing mode line and i want to put a string "Unsaved" on it, if the file is modified. How to find out directly from elisp, whether the current buffer in Emacs is modified?

Comment: Note that by default Emacs already shows you that the buffer has been modified by displaying two asterisks on the left end of the modeline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found out there is a function `buffer-modified-p`:

> Function: buffer-modified-p &optional buffer
>
> This function returns t if the buffer buffer has been modified since it was last read in from a file or saved, or nil otherwise. If buffer is not supplied, the current buffer is tested.

Source: [Emacs Lisp Reference/Buffers](http://www.zvon.org/other/elisp/Output/SEC401.html#SEC406)